# How do I change the directory of Rake? (currently /usr/bin/rake)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal, rake, macports

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3 on OS X.  I'm getting an error when I run `rake db:create` on a new installation of rails for the first time.  Here is the error in Terminal:

```
(in /Users/Michael/Sites/rails/blog)
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `bundler' for main:Object
/Users/Michael/Sites/rails/blog/Rakefile:4
```

Using which commands I get:

```
$ which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
$ which rake
/usr/bin/rake
```

I installed ruby using MacPorts, hence the opt/ path.  How do I change rake's config to go to that path instead of /usr/bin/rake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to change the PATH env variable so that the /opt/local/bin is prepended to the /usr/bin. For instance in your $HOME/.bash_profile file you could write

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right.  But, the real answer is that I switched to RVM, and it is wonderful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install Rake from MacPorts (`rb-rake`). Or, install Rake manually using the MacPorts Ruby.

Comment: Installing doesn't seem to work. Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Image error: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/rake-0.8.7.gem already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port rb-rake. Use 'port -f activate rb-rake' to force the activation.